# Publish to Azure SQL from Visual Studio 2017 - Unable to connect

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-sql-database

I recently set up an Azure SQL Database and server (using the free S0 trial).  I've been able to log in to it using SQL Server Management Studio and create a couple users, and I've been able to log in as those users through SQL Server Management Studio.  I'm also able to log in and manage the database from Visual Studio's Server Manager and SQL Server Object Explorer.

I have a SQL Database Project in my Visual Studio Solution for an app I'm working on.  Using the same connection strings that I've been using in SSMS and VS's server manager, the Database Project is unable to publish to Azure, throwing the following error:

```
Unable to connect to master or target server '{Redacted}'.
You must have a user with the same password in master or target server '{Redacted}'.
```

My IP has been added to the firewall and is set to allow access.  My username does not include the @ sign, and I have tried with and without the @servername with no change.  I also tried manually setting up the connection string, and copying/pasting the one in Azure (and populating the username and password).

I currently have the database project's `Target Platform` set to `Microsoft Azure SQL Database V12`, which matches what it reports the version as, although I have tried just `Microsoft Azure SQL Database` and `SQL Server 2016`.

Seeing as I'm able to connect from every other method I've tried so far, I assume there's something wonky in my publish profile or project that just doesn't stand out to me, or a bug in the publishing utility.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue. This happens due to the new compatibility level 140 for newly created SQL Azure databases. The issue has been documented [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/09/19/deployment-fails-with-unable-to-connect-to-master-or-target-server-mydb_svr-you-must-have-a-user-with-the-same-password-in-master-or-target-server-mydb-db/) and updating SSDT from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) to the latest version may solve the issue.

Alternatively, you can change the compatibility level of your database to 130.

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name   
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL =  130;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My google-fu apparently wasn't strong enough.  Updating SSDT worked.  Thanks!

Comment: I am glad, Thank you for the feedback.